# Fully qualify Oracle table name in Hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

**My Setup:**
I am using Hibernate 5
with the Oracle JDBC driver `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` and dialect `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect`.

My modelclasses look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MyModel1", catalog = "DB1")
public class MyModel1 {...}

@Entity
@Table(name = "MyModel2", catalog = "DB2")
public class MyModel2 {...}
```

**My Problem:**
I have multiple modelclasses that are spread about different DBs on the same DBserver.
I have to use a single DB-connection to query all of my modelclasses so I connect to DB1 for querying.
Everything would be fine, if Hibernate would generate SQL queries like

```
select * from DB1.MyModel1;
```

but it does not. For some reason it makes its queries without the catalog ie.

```
select * from MyModel1;
```

which is fine for MyModel1 because I connect to DB1 but I need a fully qualified query for MyModel2 otherwise it throws an exception, because the table of MyModel2 cannot be found in DB1.

Do you know any way to trick Hibernate or JPA or the dialect into building queries with fully qualified tablenames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Oracle you have to use the schema attribute:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MyModel1", schema= "DB1")
public class MyModel1 {...}

@Entity
@Table(name = "MyModel2", schema= "DB2")
public class MyModel2 {...}
```

Comment: I would be quiet delighted if it was that easy but it is not. the main goal is to support multiple database plattforms with a single modelclass. and for mssql i have to do it like that `@Table(name = "MyModel2", `catalog= "DB2", schema="dbo")` can you think of any other solution?

Comment: The easiest way would be if you don't relay on JPA but create synonyms in the DB for the user that is accessing the tables. Then you don't need to specify schema or catalog.